# Issue with uniqueness of the persist names in syslog-ng

Tags: logs, syslog, syslog-ng

I am new to syslog-ng and was trying to fix the issue of an error which arises due to uniqueness of the persist names in syslog-ng,
I see the below error in my syslog

> err Error checking the uniqueness of the persist names, please override it with persist-name option. Shutting down.; persist_name='afsocket_dd.(dgram,10.120.21.10:514)', location='/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf:81:26'

The current syslog-ng.conf is as below, I did a search in google and found we need to add persist-name() in order to make it unique,
but with my understanding each if the destination is already unique, with the below syslog-ng.conf, I get the error when the IP address are same, `destination d_tempask_1`  and `destination d_temst_1` have the same IP address. But if I provide a different IP address I don't see the error.
Could anybody provide some insight as to how to handle same IP address.

> source s_syslogng {
> file ("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel: "));
> unix-stream ("/run/systemd/journal/syslog" max-connections(200)); };
>
> source s_internal {
> internal();   };
>
> filter f_test1 { message("__test1"); };
>
> destination d_test1_1 { udp ( "192.168.202.119"
> port(514)  template("<$PRI>$DATE local0 infoblox Outbound[]: debug
> $MSGONLY\n") template_escape(no) ); };
>
> log { source(s_syslogng); filter(f_test1); destination(d_test1_1); };
>
> filter f_tempask { message("__tempask"); };
>
> destination d_tempask_1 { udp ( "10.120.21.10"
> port(514)  template("<$PRI>$DATE local0 infoblox Outbound[]: debug
> $MSGONLY\n") template_escape(no) ); };
>
> log { source(s_syslogng); filter(f_tempask); destination(d_tempask_1);
> };
>
> filter f_temst { message("__temst"); };
>
> destination d_temst_1 { udp ( "10.120.21.10"
> port(514)  template("<$PRI>$DATE local0 infoblox Outbound[]: debug
> $MSGONLY\n") template_escape(no) ); };
>
> log { source(s_syslogng); filter(f_temst); destination(d_temst_1); };
>
> filter f_dir { message("__dir"); };
>
> destination d_dir_1 { udp ( "10.35.183.11"
> port(514)  template("<$PRI>$DATE local0 infoblox Outbound[]: debug
> $MSGONLY\n") template_escape(no) ); };
>
> log { source(s_syslogng); filter(f_dir); destination(d_dir_1); };

tried with persist-name(), but even that still throws the error even if IP address is different or same

syslog-ng.conf with persist-name()

> source s_syslogng {
> file ("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel: "));
> unix-stream ("/run/systemd/journal/syslog" max-connections(200)); };
>
> source s_internal {
> internal();   };
>
> filter f_test1 {
> message("__test1"); };
>
> destination d_test1_1 { persist-name(test1_1) udp ( "192.168.202.119"
> port(514)  template("<$PRI>$DATE local0 infoblox Outbound[]: debug
> $MSGONLY\n") template_escape(no) ); };
>
> log { source(s_syslogng); filter(f_test1); destination(d_test1_1); };
>
> filter f_tempask { message("__tempask"); };
>
> destination d_tempask_1 { persist-name(tempask_1) udp ( "10.120.21.11"
> port(514)  template("<$PRI>$DATE local0 infoblox Outbound[]: debug
> $MSGONLY\n") template_escape(no) ); };
>
> log { source(s_syslogng); filter(f_tempask); destination(d_tempask_1);
> };
>
> filter f_temst { message("__temst"); };
>
> destination d_temst_1 { persist-name(temst_1) udp ( "10.120.21.10"
> port(514)  template("<$PRI>$DATE local0 infoblox Outbound[]: debug
> $MSGONLY\n") template_escape(no) ); };
>
> log { source(s_syslogng); filter(f_temst); destination(d_temst_1); };
>
> filter f_dir { message("__dir"); };
>
> destination d_dir_1 { persist-name(dir_1) udp ( "10.35.183.11"
> port(514)  template("<$PRI>$DATE local0 infoblox Outbound[]: debug
> $MSGONLY\n") template_escape(no) ); };
>
> log { source(s_syslogng); filter(f_dir); destination(d_dir_1); };

Any input will be very help full.

Answer (score 0):

The `persist-name()` option should go inside the destination's declaration:

```
udp("10.120.21.10" port(514) persist-name("temst_1"));
```

Comment: Still facing the same error in syslog

Comment: Make sure you use different persist names for each destinations with the same IP+port.